# symfony 3.4 data fixture

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I upgraded symfony 3.3 to 3.4 and now having problem with datafixture bundle , trying to seed data for testing but got this error :

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "addClass" of class
>   "Doctrine\ORM\Internal\CommitOrderCalculator"

this is part of my ccomposer.json file :

> "require-dev": {
>           "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
>           "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
>           "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
>       }

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I think you have to install this package too `"doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3"` its a newer version which should fix the issue

Comment: thanks , its working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upgrade the `data-fixtures` manually in your `composer.json` file. Try to upgrade it to version 1.3 like this:

```
"doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3"
```